# How can I check a string has a higher number than another string?

Tags: c#

I have two strings:

```
var a = "200309";
var b = "200317";
```

I tried

```
if (a > b)
```

But that doesn't work and gives me an error.

How can I do a check to see if one string has a greater value than the other one?

Comment: Use an `int` instead. Or if you cant, use `int.Parse` or if its user input, use `int.TryParse`

Comment: Are your strings always of equal length?

Comment: Can the strings start with a leading zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the string contains valid numbers, you could use `Int32.Parse`

```
var result = Int32.Parse(a) + Int32.Parse(b);
```

But, in case the strings are User Inputs, or there is a possibility that the numbers could be invalid, you could use `Int32.TryParse`.

For example,

```
var result = Int32.TryParse(a,out var valA) && Int32.TryParse(b,out var valB) ? 
                valA+valB 
               : throw new Exception("String cannot be converted to number");
```

Or using conventional `if` condition

```
if(Int32.TryParse(a,out var valA) && Int32.TryParse(b,out var valB))
{
    var result = valA+valB;
}
else 
    throw new Exception("String cannot be converted to number");
```

The above code checks if both numbers can be converted to `Int32`. If yes, it would produce the result, otherwise raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try This.

```
var a ="200309";
var b = "200317";

int comparison =  Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(a,b));

if(comparison>0)
{
    //Your Condition
}
else if(comparison<0)
{

}
else
{
}
```

This comparison will give you answer in (1,0,-1)
0- Your Comparison is matched.
(1,-1)- Your Comparison is not Matched.

Answer (score 1):

C# cannot work like that. Try using int.Parse() a and b and compare them as integer number.

Also, If you have to compare yy/mm/dd dates, maybe it would be better to convert them as DateTime before comparing for prevent unexpected logical problems.